# Sort list of Wordpress Page under tag when is_tag() called

Tags: tags, sort

I have a site that I'm having so much trouble to try to sort the order of a list of Pages based on their tag.

I've build this site over a year ago, with wordpress at the time there isn't any tag support for Page, so I used the plugin called tags4page. And I believe they still don't have tag support for pages ? Anyhow, my problem is if you go this page http://www.patentable.com/index.php/lawyers/ the list of Lawyers are in the right order. I can do this with wordpress build in order by giving each page a different weight.

However the **problem is** if you try to sort the list of Lawyers by selecting the drop down manual it will return a list of lawyers that are belong to this tag that you have selected. **PROBLEM** is the order are in **reversed order** for the lawyers. Is there any way to fix this ?

Right now my code is simple, basically is the following:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php /* If this is a tag archive */ if( is_tag() ) { ?>
  <h2>Lawyers in <i><?php single_tag_title(); ?></i> Practice Area:</h2>
<?php } ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
 <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
```

Comment: anybody any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge order parameters into the query when it's a tag page..

Replace the following lines.

```
<?php /* If this is a tag archive */ if( is_tag() ) { ?>
  <h2>Lawyers in <i><?php single_tag_title(); ?></i> Practice Area:</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

with..

```
<?php 
if( is_tag() ) { 
    $args = array_merge( 
        array( 'order' => 'asc', 'orderby' => 'title' ), 
        $wp_query->query
    );
    query_posts( $args ); ?>
    <h2>Lawyers in <em><?php single_tag_title(); ?></em> Practice Area:</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank YOU soo much !! you are genius I changed orderby ID works out better :P Thanks again !

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: hey by the way, what sort of attribute can i use to sort in the orderby ? I know "title" and "ID" works, can I try to sort them by the "order" value inside the wordpress Page ?

Comment: See here for possible orderby parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters

Comment: @t31os thanks once again !!! you saved my day can't thankful enough for this ! orderby menu_order is exactly what i needed :)